# Como pegar as dimensões de uma imagem durante um upload e redimensionar proporcionalmente a altura tendo como base a largura fixa?

Tags: php

Tendo como base a largura fixa, como redimensionar a altura de uma imagem de forma proporcional?

Código utilizado para redimensionar de forma fixa:

```
include("resize-class.php");
    $resizeObj = new resize("/home/roteirodoimovelc/public_html/cp/clientes/".$cliente."/".$cod."/".$imvfoto."");
    // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(600, 450, 'exact');
    $resizeObj -> saveImage("/home/roteirodoimovelc/public_html/cp/clientes/".$cliente."/".$cod."/".$imvfoto."", 100);
```

Segue o código da classe:

```
<?php

   # ========================================================================#
   #
   #  Author:    Jarrod Oberto
   #  Version:   1.0
   #  Date:      17-Jan-10
   #  Purpose:   Resizes and saves image
   #  Requires : Requires PHP5, GD library.
   #  Usage Example:
   #                     include("classes/resize_class.php");
   #                     $resizeObj = new resize('images/cars/large/input.jpg');
   #                     $resizeObj -> resizeImage(150, 100, 0);
   #                     $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/cars/large/output.jpg', 100);
   #
   #
   # ========================================================================#


        Class resize
        {
            // *** Class variables
            private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
            private $imageResized;

            function __construct($fileName)
            {
                // *** Open up the file
                $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                // *** Get width and height
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function openImage($file)
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        break;
                    case '.gif':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                        break;
                    case '.png':
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $img = false;
                        break;
                }
                return $img;
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
            {
                // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                if ($option == 'crop') {
                    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                }
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
            {

               switch ($option)
                {
                    case 'exact':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'portrait':
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'landscape':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        break;
                    case 'auto':
                        $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                    case 'crop':
                        $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                }
                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                return $newWidth;
            }

            private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                return $newHeight;
            }

            private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                if ($this->height < $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                }
                elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
                else
                // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                {
                    if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    } else {
                        // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                }

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {

                $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                    $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                } else {
                    $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                }

                $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                $crop = $this->imageResized;
                //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                $extension = strtolower($extension);

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.gif':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                            imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.png':
                        // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                        $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                        // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                        $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                             imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    // ... etc

                    default:
                        // *** No extension - No save.
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
            }


            ## --------------------------------------------------------

        }
?>
```

Comment: Depende de que biblioteca/extensao vc usa. Poste o código atual de redimensionamento, que fica mais fácil.

Comment: Essa é a chamada para o código, seria o caso de por a classe.

Comment: @Bacco publiquei o código. Trabalho com PHP.

Comment: Provavelmente tem que trocar o "exact" por outra coisa, mas sem a classe, fica dificil saber: `$resizeObj -> resizeImage(600, 450, 'exact');`. Pode ser que tenha algum método para dar resize por um dos eixos apenas.

Comment: @Bacco acrescentei a classe

Comment: @Bacco tem como depois vc fazer o teste de como redimensionar tendo como base a largura? Este código abaixo não roda certinho, as dimensões são erradas.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33645/discussion-between-gladison-neuza-perosini-and-bacco).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue código usando a biblioteca GD do PHP

```
// Sua imagem
$foto = "imagem.jpg";
$larg = 320; // largura fixa de redimensinamento

$original = imagecreatefromjpeg($foto);
$larg_foto = imagesx($original);
$alt_foto = imagesy($original);

// Fator de redimensionamento
$fator = $alt_foto / $larg_foto;

// faz o calcula da altura nova
$altura_nova = $larg * $fator;

// cria uma nova imagem com as dimensões reduzidas
$saida = imagecreatetruecolor($larg, $altura_nova);

// cria uma cópia redimensionada na imagem nova
imagecopyresized($saida, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $larg, $altura_nova, $larg_foto, $alt_foto);

// grava a imagem nova em arquivo com qualidade 80
imagejpeg($saida, "novaimagem.jpg", 80);

imagedestroy($saida);
imagedestroy($original);
```